# Centering a text in div not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to center the text in the first circle div. I think it's currently in the center of the div but when there is more than one characters like '200', it looks funky as below. I have the red circle background and trying to make the text in the center regardless of the characters. thank you in advance!

```css
.main {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;}

.main .label {
  display: inline-block;}

.bg {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60%;}

.bg .label {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">200</span></div>
    <span class="label">This is the other text need to be</span>
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">0</span></div>
    <span class="label">This is the other text need to be</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `width: 10px;`

Comment: Are you tied to using inline-block?

Comment: I tried but that didn't work

Comment: It didn't *not* work: http://jsfiddle.net/dg4t28kj/

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes I need to display them as inline block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `width:100%` on `.bg .label` as follows:

```css
.main {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;}

.main .label {
  display: inline-block;}

.bg {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60%;}

.bg .label {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">200</span></div>
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">0</span></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: if you want to keep the same width for the circle and still center the text, you could replace `width:10px;` in `.bg` with the following:

```
.bg {
  /* ... */
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* ... */
}
```

So the full snippet would look something like this:

```css
.main {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;}

.main .label {
  display: inline-block;}

.bg {
  background: red;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60%;}

.bg .label {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">200</span></div>
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">0</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi webeno, thank you. that works partially but how can I keep the same circle size as the other one please

Comment: how do you imagine that to happen? do you want to shrink the text to fit or do you just want it to center, even if the sides are overflowing outside the circle (or get very close to the rim)?

Comment: sorry, I would like to be closed to the rim. or should I use an image for the background?

Comment: i edited my answer, do you like it better like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  I'm guessing you are ok with fixing the width and height of your little circles?  If so, this solution should work for you.  The benefit here is your circles stay consistent visually regardless of the values placed within them.

You can adjust the width/height of the circle to your liking, and whatever value you place in there will remain centered.  Keep in mind, with this solution, your circles won't scale to match the value's length should it expand beyond their bounds.  I assume this is the behavior you're looking for, though, given your original code.

Also, note, you might need to adjust the top margin to position the values according to the height of the circles if you change them.  Hope this helps!

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60%;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}

.bg .label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">200</span></div>
    <span class="label">This is the other text need to be</span>
  <div class="bg"><span class="label">0</span></div>
    <span class="label">This is the other text need to be</span>
</div>
```